# How to print bitfield from struct in binary, in right way in C?

Tags: c, valgrind, bit-fields

I have a struct with several bitfields, each field must define something different in a "variable" that length of 14 bits, at the end of the process I need to print the struct like one variable in binary, I found some way,to create another struct of 14 bits, to use it like a musk, it does the job, but valgrind says 
**Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)**
is there a better way to print it? 
example with 8 bit only, but cant use char (in real need 14bit)

```
    #define MAX 8
typedef struct varNode{
    unsigned int s1:2;
    unsigned int s2:4;
    unsigned int s3:2;
}var;


void printNode(var* node){

    typedef struct {
        unsigned data:MAX;
    }mask;

    mask temp={0};
    temp.data=temp.data|((node->s1)|(node->s2<<2)|(node->s3<<6));
    unsigned x;
    x=1;
    x=x<<(unsigned )(MAX-1);
    while(x) {
        if (temp.data & x )
            printf("1");
        else printf("0");
        x>>=1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main(){
    var a={1,2,3};
    printNode(&a);
}
```

here:

```
temp.data=temp.data|((node->s1)|(node->s2<<2)|(node->s3<<6));
```

compiler warning me about signed integer operand with binary operator,can't understand why, all fields in node are unsigned

Comment: can you create example code ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]). Your structure has elements `s1` to `s6` in the bit field.  Your code shows it as having elements such as `era`, `target`, `source`, `opcode`, `param2` and `param1`.  These are not from the same structure.  Please ensure that the code you show on SO actually compiles and reproduces the problem.  We can't help you solve problems with an approximation to your real code — we probably can help you if you show the real code.

Comment: yes sorry, i try to do some example, and forgot about some elements, now i changed it to example structure, its work on compiling and print correctly, but still have a warnings

Comment: I hope,  it's ok :/

Answer (score 3):

You could use a union.

```
#include <stdio.h>
union varNode {
    struct {
       unsigned int s1:2;
       unsigned int s2:4;
       unsigned int s3:2;
   } bf;
   unsigned int num;
} var;
int main (void)
{
    // Manipulate bitfields
    var.bf.s1 = 3;
    var.bf.s3 = 1;
    // Print all of them
    printf("%d\n", var.num);
    return 0;
}
```

The bad news: the C standard leaves bitfield order to compiler implementation. The results e.g. on a low-endian Freescale HCS12 architecture is unfit for viewing by small children.

And I guarantee you, your code will end up printing all bitfields together, because that's the only efficient way of debugging.

You're better off forgetting bitfields altogether and just use integers and masks.

Comment: What a wise idea, of sometimes to avoid a specific technique in programming that is possible to implement to prevent future confusions; like, printing the complete value of a bitfield struct, that could be 8, 16 or even 32 bits which would be cool to do.

Answer (score 3):

You cat cast your data to `char` array and print it byte by byte.

```
struct varNode {
    int s1 : 2;
    int s2 : 4;
    int s3 : 2;
};

void print_byteByByte(void *pnt0, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *pnt = pnt0;
    while (size--) {
        printf("%02x", *pnt++);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct varNode var; 
    var.s1 = 1;
    var.s2 = 2;
    var.s3 = 3;

    print_byteByByte(&var, sizeof(var));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This does not break any strict aliasing rules as `char` may alias any other types.

As to your code:
`signed integer operand with binary operator` - you can declare bitfields as `_Bool` `signed int` or `unsigned int` but they have 'implementation defined type' anyway, what means signed in your architecture. Maybe silence the warning with some casting? `temp.data=temp.data|(((unsigned)node->s1)|((unsigned)node->s2<<2)|((unsigned)node->s3<<6));` I was not able to get any warnings with any `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra` options.
`Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` - I guess this is a valse positive, i don't see any uninitialized values used. My valgrind-3.13.0 with `--track-origins=yes` prints no warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Bit-fields are perverse and non-portable.  Just about everything about them - storage order, width, etc. - are "implementation-defined".

[**6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 11 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p11) states:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

So you have no real idea where your bits are going to wind up in your structure, and when you do determing where they are, if you compile with another compiler you're likely to get different results.

To add to the perversity, shifting bit-fields is subject to the rules of [**6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers** of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1):

> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same representation.
> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision.
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be
>     greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the
>     rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type, if any.
> - The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended integer type with the same width.
> - The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned char.
> - The rank of _Bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
> - The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).
> - **The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another extended signed integer type with the same precision is
>     implementation-defined**, but still subject to the other rules for
>     determining the integer conversion rank.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3.
>
> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> **If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to
>   an int**; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are
>   called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.

[Footnote 58](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note58) states:

> 58) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual
>   arithmetic conversions, to certain argument expressions, to the
>   operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of
>   the shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

Read that and tell me where bit-fields fall in the rank of integer types - is that also "implementation defined"?  If so, that would make things such as shifting a bit-field left or right even more trouble-prone.  (I suspect that would make a good language-lawyer question here on Stackoverflow - I've been looking that over for a few hours now and I can't be sure...)

Friends don't let friends use bit-fields in code.

Comment: It's not really my choice)) I need it for some university project, some "assembler" to parse text file and this may be a code for each line after parsing, in 14 bit I need to store information about the addressing metthods of variables and a number of opcode I find in text. Anyway thanks for help,  and useful information)